# MS Project Server 2007 : Programmatically toggle Task Alerts for Project Resources

Tags: task, project-server, project-server-2007, psi, project-web-access

I'm getting into SDK documentation, but this site has so many eyes and great answers I figure I'd throw this one out there to get some leads.

In project Server 2007, you can manage whether or not you get "task Alert" emails whenever a new task is assigned to you or existing tasks are modified. You can change this manually and individually via the web application under your personal settings.

As the project manager, say, I cannot toggle that for the entire team or manage it from my side. So if a resource or stakeholder who is assigned to a task(s) does not want email every time the plan is updated, I cannot handle that for them. I would have to walk them through the Project Web Access application to set it themselves manually.

So, has anyone crossed this bridge, and if so how did you toggle that flag for Task Alerts either through the SDK classes or via the PSI webservices? Before I slog through the docs, if I could get some "take a look ats..." that'd be great...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in the SQL Tables. Here's a posting on it at the project server experts page. 
www.projectserverexperts.com/ProjectServerFAQKnowledgeBase/SetDefaultEmailSubscriptions.aspx

Comment: Other than the doom-tinged warnings about MS not supporting such a direct method, sounds good, thanks